# 3D cgi movie similar to Gundam

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime, mecha

[image: The movie name]There was a movie I watched with my brother around 2010, but I'm not sure. It was on DVD; we were young and did not know much about how they got those movies at that time: they download it, put some messy subtitles on it and sell cheap.

It was a full 3d CGI movie, like [*Ultramarines: A Warhammer 40,000 Movie*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultramarines:_A_Warhammer_40,000_Movie).

It was a robot like *Gundam*, but it's not *Gundam*.
They use blade and guns rockets with their robot, but the robot design is different: it has a round belly shape and the pilot controls the robot from inside the belly of the robot.
They can use space warp dive. Spaceship battles are like those in *Star Wars*. At the final battle one of the characters and the villain's general fought near a Sun-like place with other metal things and junk floating around.

I've been looking around the internet but can't even found a clue that it ever existed. But if it does not exist how would I have watched it with my brother, who remembers it also?
Also include stars like crystals shown in the picture.

Comment: So, to be clear, this is an anime movie?

Comment: yes but not like 2d but full 3d cgi. like Ultramarine warhammer.

Comment: also they do space warping.

Comment: Ive been looking around the internet but cant even found a clue like it has never been existed. I mean if its not existed why would I watch it with brother and he also remember it.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch it? And did you watch it on TV?

Comment: Um its on dvd player. Around 2010 Im not sure. Its copy u know we were young and not know much about how they got those movies at that time. They download it do a messy subtitles and sell cheap.

Comment: Feel free to ask more.

Comment: Can you name any similar films that you know are not the one you're looking for?

Comment: gundam is the most similar. They use blade, guns rockets with their robot but robot design is different they can use space warp dive. Spaceship battles are like star wars.

Comment: I tried to put all the extra information you provided in the comments into the question. You can always [edit] it to add other details.

Comment: ok sorry. Im new here and My english is not that good. So. Thank you so much.

Comment: Good news guys. I found it after day and night searching. The movie name is"AniMen: Triton Force". I can't find it because it was Chinese movie but dub by American. Bruh because of how good that is I thought it was American or European made movie. Thx for giving your precious time to listen to my request. Also it will be my honor if you enjoy the movie together with me. And again thx you.

Comment: If you found the answer, you should post an answer instead of editing the answer into the question. Before reading the comments, I didn't understand why there was a random image at the top of the question.